# Row of StackPanels

Tags: c#, wpf, background, row, stackpanel

I'm creating a WPF application that contains `100` individual `StackPanels` that have been placed at a specific position manually, assigning to each one a starting background color. The XAML part looks like this:

```
<StackPanel Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="228,120,0,0" Name="stackPanel1"
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" Background="Red" />
<StackPanel Background="Red" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,120,0,0" 
   Name="stackPanel2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" />
<StackPanel Background="Red" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,120,0,0" 
   Name="stackPanel3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" />
<StackPanel Background="Red" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="246,120,0,0" 
   Name="stackPanel4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" />
<StackPanel Background="Red" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="252,120,0,0" 
   Name="stackPanel5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="6" />
```

As it can be seen, the `Background` is `Red` for the first 5 ones, and the `Width` is `6` (the `Margin` of each one is placed 6 units after the other to make them attached).

Now, what I want is to for example, at the .cs be able to handle them by creating a row containing them (more or less like [`stackPanel1`, `stackPanel2`, ..., `stackPanel100`]). I want to do that to, for example, change the color of the first 5 ones with the following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    if(i<10){
        stackPanelsRow[i].Background = Colors.Blue; //Change the background color to blue
    }
    if(i>10 && i<20){
        stackPanelsRow[i].Background = Colors.Green; //Change the background color to green
    }
    //...
}
```

How can I construct this row of `StackPanels` if they are individual entities created at the Designer and placed manually according to the conditions expressed above?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF you can use `Style` for this purpose:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel ... /> <!--You don't need to set background here anymore-->
    <StackPanel ... />
    ....
</Grid>
```

If you don't want to assign the same color for all the elements of the same type you can use x:Key of the style and then apply to each StackPanel that you want:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="MyStyle">
```

And then:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" ... />
```

---

**Edit:** Another option for doing this would be like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1"  Width="6" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"  Height="300" Name="stackPanel2"  Width="6" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"  Height="300" Name="stackPanel3"  Width="6" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3"  Height="300" Name="stackPanel4"  Width="6" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="4"  Height="300" Name="stackPanel5"  Width="6" />
</Grid>
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
foreach (var stackpanl in mainGrid.Children.OfType<StackPanel>())
{
     if (Grid.GetRow(stackpanl) < 2)
     {
          stackpanl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);                    
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct Sir. However, what I want to do is to change the color at the code (.cs), and not assign the same color for all the elements of the same type.

Comment: @jquery_stack...if you don't want to assign the same color for all the elements of the same type you can use `x:Key` of the style and then apply to each `StackPanel` that you want.

Comment: Is there a way to group them in a single containing unit with code? (Not XAML), and thus handle for example use stackPanelsRow[4] for the 5th stackPanel and so on instead of doing it manually with XAML? It's not a fixed style. For example, a temperature is assigned to panel 47, and if it is greater than 50ºC, the color if THIS panel must change according to a colorbar value, but this can only be done with code

Comment: @jquery_stack...it can also be done with `Triggers` in WPF and is more better. You can search about `Triggers in WPF`.

Comment: @jquery_stack...But for grouping styles the best way I think is using `styles` and `x:Key`.

Comment: I've added a picture that illustrates my problem. In the picture, there are different vertical sections, represented with stackpanels. I want to be able to handle them with CODE, not XAML, and thus I want to create somehow a vector containing all of the stackPanels.

Comment: @jquery_stack..Where are placed your `StackPanles`? In which container?

Comment: I haven't created one yet. Would that help in creating a row? Thanks :)

Comment: @jquery_stack.. Check my updated answer now. I think it's now what you want.

Comment: I'll try it tonight, but it looks like what I was looking for. Thanks a ton! If it works, I'll press the tick sign :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your stack panels by StackPanel

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelTest" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel/>
    <StackPanel/>
    <StackPanel/>
</StackPanel>
```

And you can access like

```
var someStackPanel = StackPanelTest.Children[0] as StackPanel;
```

Comment: Would it work if I just write StackPanelTest.Children[0].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue); at the code without declaring the 100 of them at the code? If this works, my question will be solved :)